# Need to get absolute list of urls for files stored on file server using curl/wget

Tags: python, linux, shell, curl, wget

I have bunch of files(more than 50K) stored at the server:

```
http://fileserver1.com/sec-test/compressed/mango/exe/small/
```

I need to get a file which has 50 files entry of the absolute URL for my tests without downloading the files. For instance:

file_output:

```
http://fileserver1.com/sec-test/compressed/mango/exe/small/1.exe
http://fileserver1.com/sec-test/compressed/mango/exe/small/2.exe
http://fileserver1.com/sec-test/compressed/mango/exe/small/3.exe
...
http://fileserver1.com/sec-test/compressed/mango/exe/small/50.exe
```

Tried a couple of curl and wget commands. I am able to download the files recursively but not getting the path of the file from the file server stored somewhere.

`wget -r -np -k http://fileserver1/sec-test/compressed/mango/exe/small/ > /dev/null`

Please can someone help how can I achieve it. Thanks in advance

Comment: HTTP doesn't provide any standard way to list a directory. Your webserver might be configured to automatically generate a listing file when you request a directory, but the format of this list is not standardized.

Comment: @Barmar..Thanks for your reply. Can you elaborate with an example what can I add/change on the server? Maybe using find command

Comment: What you should do is implement an API that returns the information you want in JSON format.

Comment: Actually, got the answer..used find command to get the files and store it in a file. Then replace the urls using find and replace from the output file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> get a file which has 50 files entry of the absolute URL for my tests
> without downloading the files

When using `wget` you might combine `-r` with `--spider` option, then `wget` will only download files which might contain further links and check others by sending [`HEAD` requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/methods/head), it will write what was done to stderr, which then you might process to extract URL, for example to trawl `wget` manual page you might do

```
wget --spider -r 'https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html'
```